# How to connect to Dockerhub registry from nestjs app

Tags: nestjs, artifactory, dockerhub, amazon-ecr, google-artifact-registry

Given a registry URL, username and password, how to connect to the Dockerhub registry from nestJs app. I need the code to create the client or perform actions like creating a new repository from inside the app only. Want to do something similar to Google Artifact Registry or AWS ECR Client...
How to do it? Where can I find relevant references for them?

Comment: Try this curl example and then port it to your nestJS app code.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60549217/2777988

Comment: Don't we have any npm package to manage the APIs like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/artifact-registry ?